# What is the purpose of bitdepth for the several components of the framebuffer in glfwWindowHint function of GLFW3?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glfw

I would like to know what are the following "framebuffer related hints" of GLFW3 function glfwWindowHint :

- GLFW_RED_BITS
- GLFW_GREEN_BITS
- GLFW_BLUE_BITS
- GLFW_ALPHA_BITS
- GLFW_DEPTH_BITS
- GLFW_STENCIL_BITS

What is the purpose of this? Usually their default values are enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use those to request that the OS give you a GL context with *at least* that many bits of r/g/b/alpha/depth/stencil.  It may give you more.

If you don't set explicit values for each hint GLFW will [use zeros](https://github.com/elmindreda/glfw/blob/master/src/window.c#L165) instead.

Some (most? all?) GL implementations won't give you any alpha/depth/stencil bits unless you specifically ask for them.

You'll almost certainly get some color bits though.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! But I'm still confused...Where are those bits stored? In a buffer in the GPU? What do they affect?